# DRAYTEK - VLANs with VLAN tagging switches / router

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, draytek

Our company uses Draytek routers (various models, slowly upgrading to 2860n at each site).

We have recently purchased a new site, and want to split the network up into separate VLANs, so as to allow several different tenants internet access using our router, but on their own network.

We have a netgear GS724T, which can up to 128 VLANs operating across it, however the 2860n seems to only support 8 (VLAN0-VLAN7).

Is it possible to configure a 2860n (or similar small/medium business router) to route all VLAN tagged traffic from our managed switch, if I assign more than 10 VLANs to various ports on the switch? Is it as simple as a single cable from the 2860n to the switch, and configuring that port (on the switch) as the trunk, and then configuring 1 or more of the remaining ports on the switch for each of the 10+ VLANs?

Your assistance in this will be much appreciated!